# Google Play in app update not working if app installed with package manager

Tags: android, in-app-update, google-play-core

I am using Google Play in-app updates to notify my uses for new updates. But the problem is in-app updates not working if the app is not installed from Google Play store.

With some curiosity how my production app in app updates working, I downloaded a lower version universal signed APK from play console and installed in my mobile. All is working fine but not getting in-app updates for that app.

Same version app on other device which is installed from Google play store is getting in-app updates.

Is this a bug in the play core API, or I did any mistake?